# How not to send any data to client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use Ruby-on-Rails in my project and there is a functionality to delete the whole data from table in one click. And in that case, I don't want to send any data to client from server. To do that, I wrote this part of code:

`render :json => {}`

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use

```
head :ok
```

which returns an empty response with the HTTP status code `200 (OK)`.

Docs about [`head`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Head.html#method-i-head).

Comment: i. e. I must write: `render head :ok`?

Comment: No, it is just `head :ok` (not `render`). `head` is a method on its own and it is basically a short cut for `render nothing: true, status: :ok`